# Can a Mystic use more than one discipline in the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, designer-reasons

Even if psionic disciplines are different from spells (as psionic is different from magic in general), there seems to be a clear correspondence between them, as well as between psionic talents and cantrips, because in some way things must get balanced.

Spells have an explicit limitation when it comes to how many of them you can cast in a turn. If you cast a spell that requires a bonus action, you can then use your action only to cast a cantrip.

I haven't seen a similar limitation for psionic disciplines. Did I miss it somewhere? If not, have *the developers* said why psionics doesn't have that restriction?

<sub>Answers regarding developer intent **must** include quotes from the devs. Speculation is **not** acceptable.</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### As long as the action economy and psi limit allow it, yes

We see on page three of the [Mystic class description](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf):

> Psionics   is  a   special form    of  magic   use,    distinct    from spellcasting.

Based on this, it would be inappropriate to use the standard spellcasting rules when using disciplines. Additionally, page 9 states:

> The    discipline  specifies   the type    of  action  and
> number  of  psi points  it  requires.   It  also    details whether you must    concentrate on  its effects,    how many    targets it  affects,    what    saving  throws  it  requires,   and so  on.

As you have noted, nowhere else in the class description mentions a limitation on the number of disciplines that you can cast in a turn, and we shouldn't assume that any rule carries over from regular spellcasting. Based on that, the most specific rules that we have is the standard action economy rules: you can only take 1 action and bonus action per turn, and are limited to 1 reaction a round.

Additionally, Jeremy Crawford has been asked [this very question](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/03/20/how-do-talentsdisciplines-interact-with-rules-for-casting-a-bonus-action-spell/) on twitter and he replied:

> The rule on casting a spell as a bonus action applies only to spells.

Since Disciplines are not spells, they are not held to the same limitation. As long as you have an action/bonus action/reaction left to use a discipline and the proper number of psi-points, you can continue to use your disciplines as you see fit.

### Keep in mind your psi-limit though

The mystic does have the limitation that:

> There  is  a   limit   on  the number  of  psi points  you can spend   to activate a   psionic discipline.
> The    limit is based  on  your
> mystic  level,  as  shown   in  the Psi Limit   column  of
> the Mystic  table. For  example,    as  a   3rd-level   mystic,
> you can spend   no  more    than    3   psi points  on  a
> discipline each time    you use it, no  matter  how
> many    psi points  you have

This doesn't prevent you from using multiple different disciplines in one turn, but it does limit the way that you can use your disciplines in a manner similar to the spell slot levels that a typical spellcaster has.

### Have the developers said why disciplines aren't restricted like spells?

Sort of. Often, as with the [Kensai Monk](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/12/14/if-you-could-immediately-change-one-thing-about-the-new-ua-monk-features-what-wo), the Unearthed Arcana material intentionally experiments with unusual features, for example not immediately making Kensai Weapons also Monk Weapons. They could be performing a similar experiment here. The spirit of this material is that the DM will make a call regarding ambiguity in the class, and then the surveys will inform the team about how people are playing the class. Or as JC put it [here](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/03/16/the-mystic-is-an-experiment-that-uses-disciplines-instead-of-spells/):

> The mystic is an example of us testing a concept in UA: is it fun to represent a different mode of magic with a different subsystem?

Based on this, I would say that their decision not to have the mystic follow the same rules is intentional.